# Socket connect timeouts: where is the specification?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

The context of my work is my local area network.

The code samples below are written in Java language but my question is about TCP, not programming.

I have experienced the following connection timeout:

- ```
   2 ms when connection established
  ```
- 1 005 ms when host is alive but not listen on the specified socket port
- 21 000 ms when host is down

This values comes from observation of my network but I presume it exists a RFC.

Here is some information about timeout:

- [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122)
- [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)
- [Nagle's_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) and TCP_NO_DELAY

Can you give me more pointers?

```
@Override
public void run() {
   for( int port = _portFirst; port < _portLast; ++port ) {
      String  host    = "192.168.1." + _address;
      boolean success = false;
      long    before  = System.currentTimeMillis();
      try {
         Socket        socket   = new Socket();
         SocketAddress endpoint = new InetSocketAddress( host, port );
         socket.connect( endpoint, 0 );
         success = true;
         socket.close();
      }// try
      catch( ConnectException c ){/**/}
      catch( Throwable t ){
         t.printStackTrace();
      }
      long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
      System.err.println( host + ":" + port + " = " + duration );
      _listener.hostPinged( host, port, success, duration );
   }
}
```

Comment: These timeouts are controlled by your OS, which OS/Version do you have?

Comment: BTW port scanning can be easily done by existing tools like `nmap` I would consider using it if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I know nmap, http://www.lookatlan.com or http://overlooksoft.com but my goal is to acquire fundamental knowledge

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no RFC for connection timeouts. It is impossible for any RFC or other document to know the conditions prevailing in any network in advance.

In general you can expect a successful connection to be very quick; an `ECONNREFUSED` (`ConnectException: connection refused`) to be about as quick; and a connection timeout (`ConnectException: connect timeout`) to take as long as it takes, depending on the cause, the platforms at both ends, and the nature of the intervening network. In Windows I believe a connection timeout consists of the total time across three connection attempts with timeouts 6s, 12s, and 24s, total  42s; in various Unixes I believe the total is more like 70s, which could result from 3 attempts with timeouts 10s, 20s, and 40s. As you see it is up to the platform. There is also the issue that filling the backlog queue at a Windows server will cause RSTs to be issued to incoming SYNs, where on a Unix/Linux server it will cause no response at all to incoming SYNs.

You should also note that in Java, and contrary to many years of Javadoc:

1. A zero connect timeout does not imply an infinite timeout, it implies the platform default timeout, which as shown above isn't above about 70s;
2. You cannot specify a connection timeout that increases the platform default; you can only use it to decrease the platform default.

Comment: But timeouts are sometimes specified in RFC... So it's not "impossible"

Comment: @Aubin It's not impossible for RFCs to specify timeouts, but then I didn't say it was.

Comment: what if I want to implement tcp longpolling techniques. Can I somehow get above this max system timeout?

Comment: @tobi Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. No.

Comment: @EJP ok. So I guess I'm safe if my long polling waits for a maximum of 60 seconds or so.

Answer (score 2):

As you have found out, you can specify a timeout in the `connect(...)` method call as such:

```
connect( SocketAddress endpoint , int timeout )
```

And remember that ["...A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29) (where "infinite" often really means "use the OS default").

As for the defaults, they are OS dependent, but usually fairly consistent anyways. If you're on a linux box, have a look at `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive*` (but don't change them unless you know what you're doing :-)

Cheers,

Comment: However, and regardless of the Javadoc, a connect timeout of zero is *not* actually 'interpreted as an infinite timeout'. Try it and see.

Comment: `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive*` has nothing to do with connect timeouts.

Comment: I'm personally up against an issue right now where I'm still receiving the timeout despite setting a very long timeout in my connect invocation. It's not respecting the value I assume because it's hitting the timeout earlier than when the timeout I specify matters? How can this be?

Comment: @buddyp450 See my answer. It had already been there for six years when you posted that comment.