# how does httpclient 4.3 default timeout setting work, if not setting connectiontimeout, connectionmanagertimeout, and sockettimeout?

Tags: java, httpclient

I have recently used httpclient 4.3, I know api has been changed, but if not setting timeout threshold(conenction or socket or conenctionmanager), it can work, which means no infinite loop query, and method.getResponseBodyAsString() would return an empty string, but in the document, it said that default parameter setting of timeout is infinite, so how does it work?

```
public class ContentModelUtils {
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
...
    public static String fetchPlainHttpResult(String id, Map<String, String> result, String getUrl)
                throws HttpException, IOException {
            method = new GetMethod(fetchPlainUrl(id, result, getUrl));
            //client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout",1000);
            //client.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout",1000);
            //client.getParams().setParameter("http.connection-manager.timeout",10000L);
            client.executeMethod(method);
            if (method.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                return null;
            }
            String outputValue = new String(method.getResponseBodyAsString());

            return outputValue;
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The default setting is in fact an infinite timeout.  To prove this, let's browse the [source repository for Apache HttpCore 4.3.x](https://github.com/apache/httpcore/tree/4.3.x).

In [BasicConnFactory](https://github.com/apache/httpcore/blob/4.3.x/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/pool/BasicConnFactory.java#L78), we can see it pulling the connect timeout setting, and the line of code that retrieves the timeout parameter uses a default of `0`.

```
this.connectTimeout = params.getIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

Later, in [BasicConnFactory#create](https://github.com/apache/httpcore/blob/4.3.x/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/pool/BasicConnFactory.java#L173), this timeout value is passed into a socket connection.

```
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port), this.connectTimeout);
```

According to the documentation of [Socket#connect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)), a timeout value of `0` (which we saw earlier is the default) is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

> Connects this socket to the server with a specified timeout value. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. The connection will then block until established or an error occurs.

Comment: The Javadoc is incorrect on this point. A zero connect timeout is interpreted as the platform default timeout, which is around a minute. The connect timeout cannot be increased beyond this default, only decreased.

Comment: I prefer to agree with EJP, because by testing, I think it really wait about 1minute and then exit without infinite loop, but I could not get any documents by saying 1 minute, could you help me?

Comment: @richardzrc, if the intent of your question is "what is the contract of HttpClient 4.3 with no explicit timeout set", then my answer stands.  If instead the intent is "why am I really seeing a ~1 minute timeout even though JavaDocs say infinite", then I suggest we close this as duplicate of another question EJP already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266403/socket-connect-timeouts-where-is-the-specification.  (@EJP, thanks for commenting here.)  JavaDoc is technically correct but potentially misleading, because it ignores the possibility of timeout policy enforced by the OS.